# Load UIWebView Page in Second UIWebView Without Reload?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I am working on some kind of tab functionality in my app so the user can switch between web pages they have open just like in any browser.

Is it possible to have a page loaded in one webview and then transfer the data to a second web view so it can be displayed without requiring the user to re-download the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a page loaded in one webview and then transfer the data to a second web view so it can be displayed without requiring the user to re-download the page?

Instead of doing this, why don't you swap your first and second web view? So, the first web view would replace the second (it would not need to be reloaded), and then you would download a second page in the latter.

As an aside, you could copy the content of the first web view into the second by doing:

```
NSString* body = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body"];
```

then:

```
[secondWebView loadHTMLString:body baseURL:nil];
```

but this would not be very efficient: the HTML would not be downloaded a second time, still it should be rendered by the second web view (and this would cost some time, so you would have a delay). Much better to swap the web views.

Answer (score 0):

Simply.. that's not possible. As far as i know is not possible to share data between different instance of UIWebview